# Arch Linux ISO: Boots with issues, and Wi-Fi breaks

Tags: arch-linux

I am having a major problem with the Arch Linux installer ISO (archiso). On my UEFI computer, it does boot from the USB, however I see a lot of errors, and about 5 pages of code spam the screen before it gets to the "automatic login" part. And then, when it finally *gets* to the login part, 4 more errors appear on the screen. These errors are so precise and long, I can't even notice what they are exactly *saying*. Furthermore, I cannot connect to Wi-Fi after it does boot, since my only Wi-Fi interface (wlp2s0) does not show. I feel like this is a problem with my computer itself, because I have troubleshooted with all the following:

- Same problem when ISO is written on a different USB pen.
- All other distros' ISOs boot fine on the same installation media: Debian and Ubuntu work perfectly.
- The same archiso installation media boots perfectly correctly on my other computer, which also uses UEFI.
- I never had this problem before; it worked perfectly fine before. It's only recently it's come about

So, because of this, I tried the following to resolve it:

- Clearing the UEFI NVRAM
- Re-flashing the UEFI Firmware (yes, I even went *this* far!)

And after all of this, it still doesn't work. I don't know what to do. If Wi-Fi breaks I don't want to even begin to *think* what other hardware breaks!

**EDIT:** Output of `dmesg`:

Since the output is very long, I have logged it all to a text file, accessible from here:

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V8kBq-IB32o_Nim3rYLsb3-zxNwngLwL)

Comment: After you log in, you should have `dmesg` available, so you can show us what are the exact errors you're getting.

Comment: @schaiba Question edited to include it.

Comment: Use `dmesg | less`, which will show output one screen at a time, then, if you can't paste, take pictures and add the link to them. That video is not of much use.

Comment: @schaiba I have managed to log `dmesg` into a text file, which I have edited the question to link to instead of the video.

Comment: So you have a Chromebook. The Arch wiki has an entry for those devices here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices

Comment: @schaiba But it worked perfectly fine before (about 2 weeks aho), and I have not changed anything. This only came around in the last few days. I have read the Wiki page on ChromeOS devices :).